# Is the subjunctive mood used in the last sentence?

Tags: meaning, usage

That is, is ***the statement that internet access increased individual economic fitness*** imaginary or real?
If I define individual economic fitness as ***an individual's ability to survive and thrive in a particular economic environment***, I think the ***if*** clause in the last sentence describes the unreal situation because internet access does not help the economic lives of working Americans improve.

> In the 1990s, the story went that access to certain tools — an
> internet connection and a PC — would enable access to high-wage jobs.
> Today, it appears that the tools were easier to get than the jobs.
> Ultimately, we must reckon with the fact that as home internet access
> has reached a saturation point — though of course gaps still remain —
> the economic lives of working Americans have either not improved or
> have worsened. Hourly wages have stagnated since the late 1970s, while
> productivity has continued to improve (Bivens et al. 2014). Indeed,
> from 2000 to 2013, the era wherein home internet access reached the
> saturation point, hourly wages for 30 percent of the workforce
> actually fell. The story is worse for workers with only a high school
> degree, but even college graduates have seen anemic wage growth. And
> while gender-based wage gaps have narrowed over the last forty years,
> race-based ones have been stubbornly persistent (Bivens et al. 2014;
> see also Akee, Jones, and Porter 2019; Author and Dorn 2014; Dumenil
> and Levy 2015; Edelman 2013). ***This is hardly the picture we’d
> expect if internet access increased individual economic fitness.***

[The Promise of Access: Technology, Inequality, and the Political Economy of Hope](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=fDoiEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=And%20while%20gender-based%20wage%20gaps%20have%20narrowed%20over%20the%20last%20forty%20years,%20race-%20based%20ones%20have%20been%20stubbornly%20persistent.%20This%20is%20hardly%20the%20picture%20we%E2%80%99d%20expect%20if&source=bl&ots=h16c21qvX0&sig=ACfU3U3lFUAqpkCvO7S1OUGsl1JSdYorYA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-mZ__7Kj4AhWJOZQKHdDqCkEQ6AF6BAghEAM#v=onepage&q=And%20while%20gender-based%20wage%20gaps%20have%20narrowed%20over%20the%20last%20forty%20years%2C%20race-%20based%20ones%20have%20been%20stubbornly%20persistent.%20This%20is%20hardly%20the%20picture%20we%E2%80%99d%20expect%20if&f=false)

Comment: No, it's not subjunctive. It's just a conditional construction. Subjunctive clauses have a plain form of the verb, as in "It is vital that I **be** told immediately".

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

The last sentence is short for

> This is hardly the picture we would expect if internet access increased individual economic fitness.

The author is pointing to a hypothetical world in which internet usage helped make people richer, and showing that that is not the real world.

Comment: But it's not subjunctive. It's just a conditional construction expressing modal remoteness. Subjunctive clauses have a plain form of the verb, as in "It is vital that I **be** told immediately".